# How can I exclude DTSTART from generated events if its day not among days specified by BYDAY?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445, rrule

I'm using [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-rfc-2445/) to generate repeating events according to according to [rfc-2445](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt):

> The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive start of
>   the event. For recurring events, it also specifies the very first
>   instance in the recurrence set.

So, for example RRULE for event which occures every Friday 5 times:

```
DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:20160204T090000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=FR;INTERVAL=1;
```

So according to [rfc-2445](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) it will generate 6 events. First event on `Thursday 4 February 2016`, second event on `Friday 5 February 2016`, and so on.

How can I achieve that it will exclude first event if it isn't in a pattern? In the example above it should exclude first occurrence, `4 February 2016`. In case of defining `DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:20160205T090000` which is Friday it should leave first occurrence.

Can it be done by defining such "exclusion rule" in `RRULE` itself or I need to make a check in a code and if `DTSTART` isn't the same day as defined in `BYDAY` I should look for closest date in code (manually) and change `DTSTART` accordingly?

**UPDATE**
Ok, according to rfc-2445 and this question on google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-rfc-2445/xqYFe411ysA

> The "EXDATE" property can be used to exclude the value specified in
>   "DTSTART". However, in such cases the original "DTSTART" date MUST
>   still be maintained by the calendaring and scheduling system because
>   the original "DTSTART" value has inherent usage dependencies by other 
>   properties such as the "RECURRENCE-ID".

it looks that I need to use `EXDATE` property to achieve what do I need. Trying to achieve this by following RRULE:

```
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20160210T000000 
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=WE;INTERVAL=1;
```

And start date is: `2016-02-10T00:00:00.000+02:00` in the following code:

```
DateTimeIterable dti = DateTimeIteratorFactory.createDateTimeIterable(RRULE, DTSTART, dateTimeZone, true);
```

But it returns only 4 events, so it **always** remove first event.

Comment: This will generate 5 events, due to `COUNT=5`. DTSTART counts as the first instance, so there will be only 4 Friday events.

Comment: No, It returns 6 events, event which specified by DTSTART and 5 events by pattern.

Comment: That's a bug in the library. [RFC 5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.10) clearly says `The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which to range-bound the recurrence.  The "DTSTART" property value always counts as the first occurrence.`

Comment: FTR, that's also true for [RFC 2445](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445#section-4.3.10)

Comment: As you noticed `EXDATE` is not a solution. Unless you have support for that in your recurrence library it's not trivial to determine if `DTSTART` matches the rule or not. Given that most implementations return `DTSTART` as the first instance, why do you want to handle it differently?

Comment: I'm writing a Calendar app. It should behave similar to Lotus Notes, Google Calendar. When you select pattern, for example: `weekly, 3 times by Friday` but user selected start of sequence at `4th February` which is  Thursday, it moves start to first occurrence of repeating pattern from above, first occurrence of Friday which is 5th February. I just looking to achieve this by using **rfc-2445** library without doing manual calculation prior to parsing. Less code, less bugs, etc... But I see that I haven't another solution, only evaluate start date manually.

Comment: So what you really want is the first instance that matches the rule ... I've already thought about such a feature for our own recurrence iterator [lib-recur](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur) shouldn't be too difficult to add ...

Comment: Despite the fact that it can be very helpful I think that you should stick to specification, IMHO. Btw, except build rules feature and "it's always good to have some alternatives" are there any advantages in your implementation over `rfc-2445-google` or `calendarcommon2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102605/discussion-between-marten-and-anatoly).

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the problem you give, you will get 6 events when `DTSTART` is added and you would not want it to be part of the list of instances and 5 events when it is a *good* date.

So what you want is to only get the **last** 5 events, which is possible by using the `BYSETPOS` in your `RRULE`, the following should do the trick:

> BYSETPOS=-5,-4,-3,-2,-1

which will return in all cases the last 5 events that your `RRULE` gives regardless if the `DTSTART` is matching the pattern of your `RRULE` or not.