# How can I check with joda-time is it first, second, ... , or last week of a month by given date?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jodatime, java-time

For example:

- `5 February 2016` - first week,
- `12 February 2016`- second week,
- `28 February 2016`- last week

Comment: This is tagged [tag:java-time]. Are you also possibly looking for a Java Time solution? (new Java 8 Time API)?

Comment: Actually no, I'm looking for joda-time solution. Just thought that it might be similarity between API and solution for Java-Time suitable for Joda-Time too.

Comment: I'm afraid Joda-Time does not support week of month out of the box... One would have to come up with a tricky implementation. It is included in Java Time though.

Comment: @Tunaki I fear it is not even possible with Java 8 (JSR-310) without writing an own complex adjuster or field due to the fact that [weekOfMonth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfMonth--) also defines week zero which is probably not what the OP wants. The month equivalent to `weekOfWeekBasedYear()` is missing in `java.time`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I noticed that it used week 0 yes. It really depends on what definition of "week of month" the OP wants to have. [ISO-8601](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO), which Java Time has, says that "first week has a minimum of 4 days"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not quite clear how you define the week of month. For the following discussion, **I assume you speak about weeks starting on Monday (like in ISO-8601-standard and in most European countries).**

There are two possible ways of definition how to handle the start and end of month when counting the weeks.

Since the start of week on Monday is not necessarily the same as the first day of month, **a week can start in previous month or belong to next month**.

The JDK-classes `SimpleDateFormat` with its field pattern symbol w (and also the new JSR-310-field [WeekFields.weekOfMonth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfMonth--)) use following strategy:

> If the first day of month is falling on Monday to Thursday then the
>   associated week has at least 4 days in current month and will be
>   counted as week 1 otherwise as week 0 (zero). Consistently the last
>   day of month will always use an incrementing number even if it belongs
>   to first week of next month.

In contrast to that definition, CLDR date-time-pattern specification and ISO-8601 are almost silent about the details in context of week-of-month. However, these standards are not silent about the week-of-year where they describe another strategy. And [CLDR explicitly says about week-of-month](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (section 8.4):

> 8.4 Week of Year
>
> Values calculated for the Week of Year field range from 1 to 53 for
>   the Gregorian calendar (they may have different ranges for other
>   calendars). Week 1 for a year is the first week that contains at least
>   the specified minimum number of days from that year. Weeks between
>   week 1 of one year and week 1 of the following year are numbered
>   sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (if needed). For example, January 1,
>   1998 was a Thursday. If the first day of the week is MONDAY and the
>   minimum days in a week is 4 (these are the values reflecting ISO 8601
>   and many national standards), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December
>   29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. However, if the first day of
>   the week is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and
>   ends on January 10, 1998. The first three days of 1998 are then part
>   of week 53 of 1997.
>
> **Values are similarly calculated for the Week of Month.**

The difference between both strategies applied on the date 2016-02-29 will be:

- week 5 according to JDK
- week 1 according to CLDR/ISO

---

Now I present a **solution for Joda-Time**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println(getWeekOfMonth(false)); // CLDR/ISO-spec
    // 1 for today=2016-02-05
    // 2 for today=2016-02-12
    // 4 for today=2016-02-28
    // 1 for today=2016-02-29

    System.out.println(getWeekOfMonth(true)); // JDK-behaviour
    // 1 for today=2016-02-05
    // 2 for today=2016-02-12
    // 4 for today=2016-02-28
    // 5 for today=2016-02-29

}

private static int getWeekOfMonth(boolean bounded) {
    int weekOfMonth;
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    LocalDate first = today.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
    int dowFirst = first.getDayOfWeek();

    if (dowFirst <= DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY) {
        // we are in week 1 and go to Monday as start of week
        first = first.minusDays(dowFirst - DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);

        // first try: we determine the week of current month
        weekOfMonth = Days.daysBetween(first, today).getDays() / 7 + 1;

        if (!bounded) {
            // edge case: are we in first week of next month?
            LocalDate next = first.plusMonths(1);
            int dowNext = next.getDayOfWeek();

            if (dowNext <= DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY) {
                next = next.minusDays(dowNext - DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
                if (!next.isAfter(today)) {
                    weekOfMonth = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (bounded) {
        weekOfMonth = 0;
    } else {
        // we are in last week of previous month so let's check the start of previous month
        LocalDate previous = first.minusMonths(1);
        int dowPrevious = previous.getDayOfWeek();

        if (dowPrevious <= DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY) {
            previous = previous.minusDays(dowPrevious - DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
        } else {
            previous = previous.plusDays(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY - dowPrevious + 7);
        }

        weekOfMonth = Days.daysBetween(previous, today).getDays() / 7 + 1;
    }

    return weekOfMonth;
}
```

I hope it is not too complex for you.

---

By the way, if you are interested how simple alternatives applicable on platforms older than Java-8 look like:

[Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (my library)

```
private static int time4j(boolean bounded) { // supports both definitions
  PlainDate today = SystemClock.inLocalView().today(); // using system timezone
    return today.get(
          (bounded ? Weekmodel.ISO.boundedWeekOfMonth() : Weekmodel.ISO.weekOfMonth()));
}
```

[Threeten-BP (backport of Java-8):](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp)

```
private static int threeten() { // only JDK-definition (code similar to Java-8)
    org.threeten.bp.LocalDate today = org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.now();
    return today.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth());
}
```

[Old JDK:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

```
private static int oldJDK() { // only JDK-definition
    GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
    gcal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    return gcal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
}
```

As you can see, it is very easy with these alternatives to change the underlying week models to non-ISO cases (like US-weeks). If you want that in Joda-Time then I leave the task for you to rewrite the presented Joda-solution.

**Update due to comment below about the topic:**

So the whole thing is about **day-of-week-in-month**. Joda-Time does not support this element/field out of the box, too. Sorry. But you might be able to study the [necessary algorithm](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/time4j/WeekdayInMonthElement.java) for such a field used in other libraries.

A demo example in Time4J for modelling the rfc2445-rule mentioned in comment:

```
    PlainDate dtStart = PlainDate.of(2016, Month.FEBRUARY, 4);
    int count = 5;
    Weekday byday = Weekday.FRIDAY; // first
    int interval = 1;
    CalendarUnit frequency = CalendarUnit.MONTHS;

    List<PlainDate> sequence = new ArrayList<>(count);
    PlainDate wim = dtStart;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        wim = wim.with(PlainDate.WEEKDAY_IN_MONTH.setToFirst(byday));
        sequence.add(wim);
        wim = wim.with(PlainDate.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1).plus(interval, frequency);
    }
    if (!sequence.isEmpty() && !sequence.get(0).equals(dtStart)) {
        sequence.remove(0); // Not quite sure - do you need another condition?
    }
    System.out.println(sequence); // [2016-03-04, 2016-04-01, 2016-05-06, 2016-06-03]
```

In **Java-8**, there is also support via a [specialized adjuster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-) so you can easily transfer given demo example to Java-8 using `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Actually this answer is sequel to my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197441/how-can-i-exclude-dtstart-from-generated-events-if-its-day-not-among-days-specif  I need to exclude first day defined by DTSTART if not among RRULE. In rfc-2445 I can define repeat rule to be `1st monday`, `2nd monday`, `last monday` by `1MO,2MO,-1MO`. To know if DTSTART is among this Mondays and leave it, or if isn't to remove it, I should know which day and which week DTSTART is.

Comment: @Anatoly Hm, are you still talking about week-of-month, or do you mean day-of-week-in-month? This is not quite the same. Your repeat rule sounds rather like `SimpleDateFormat`-pattern symbol F, or special [JSR-310-adjuster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth-int-java.time.DayOfWeek-) or in Time4J this [interface.](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/OrdinalWeekdayElement.html). For Joda-Time there is no such equivalent, too so another workaround is necessary.

Comment: I'll give short example. I've the following RRULE: `FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=1FR;INTERVAL=1;` Where DTSTART is 04-Feb-2016 I.e. every month, first Friday of the month should be select 5 times, the dates are: 5-Feb-2016, 4-Mar-2016,1-Apr-2016,6-May-2016,3-Jun-2016. But user selected start of this sequence at 4-Feb-2016 which isn't 1st Friday but  1st Thursday. I need to check which this and leave it or remove. I'll implement your examples tomorrow to see what is more suitable for me, thank you. The only one problem is regarding LPGL license of your library, don't know if I could use it.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry but I really need `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH  I am ashamed but I incorrectly formulated my question. Anyway, your answer to my question as I've asked it was correct and at least I hope that it will help somebody

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks for clarification. About LGPL, I am just concerned about the situation where any user might have an outdated version and ask you for a newer version of Time4J embedded in your app. But of course this is open and free source.

Answer (score 0):

In jdk 8 you could implement your own  TemporalAdjusters
and use  with LocalDate.with()